# Check which column throws the UniqueConstraintViolationException

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

An easy one (hopefully):

When saving an entity that has multiple unique indexes, how to know which one is throwing the exception? I guess that if several fail at the same time I'll only catch one, and that's ok. But still would like to know which to report back to the user, if I can.

Throwing back the exception message or responding "one of these fields failed" is not great.

My code does something like:

```
try {
     $this->getEntityManager()->persist($user);
     $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

     $response
         ->setPayload($user)
         ->setStatus(Response::STATUS_OK)
         ->setType(Response::SINGLE);
} catch (UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
     $response
         ->setStatus(Response::STATUS_ERROR)
         ->setMessage('Whish I knew what column failed. Alas, I only know something went wrong.');
}
```

The ORM definiton has something like:

```
TresMonitos\SomeBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: user
    repositoryClass: TresMonitos\SomeBundle\Repository\UserRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        username:
            type: string
            length: '25'
            unique: true
        email:
            type: string
            length: '100'
            unique: true
```

I get the `UniqueConstraintViolationException`, but I fail to see in `$e` how to identify the column. The message just refers to the index. For completeness sake:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'xxx' for key 'UNIQ_8D93D649F85E0677.

I can query the DB before I attempt the insert, to find if I have existing rows that match any of these fields (which I guess I'll have to do if the answer is *not solvable*).

Comment: Do you mean you want to parse the error in code in order to find the column that this constraint is talking about

Comment: No, that's exactly what I **don't** want to do. I want to know if there is a way provided by **doctrine** to find information about the failing column.

Comment: Can you show us whats in `$user`

Comment: No, because is not relevant **at all**.

Comment: And you should be able to see the implicated fields in the orm definition...

Comment: In my opinion is the approach the real problem. I think you should validate properly the data before storing them to avoid to have this type of problem

Comment: So query the DB before inserting. I thought I would end up like that...

Comment: @gp_sflover, despite agreeing that that is probably the correct approach (but is a different question), is there a way to find out which column is the one that triggers the exception?

Comment: I don't think it is possible without parsing the exception data and I never heard (or see) about some built-in method provided by Doctrine to achieve what you want.

Comment: It s a bit unfortunate that Doctrine does not allow you to name the index.  However, you can map UNIQ_8D93D649F85E0677 to a column name(s).  It won't change unless you drop the schema.  You can also dump doctrine generated sql to a file and then give the indexes a better name.  And yes it would be nice if mysql generated a better error message.

Comment: UniqueEntity constraint should be your best bet to do that symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html